# Device not display MediaController

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am using the below code to test on emulator and device, the result came out was, the emulator can show the MediaController just below the VideoView(default is at the bottom of the screen). However, when I tested in device, it does not show me the MediaController.
I would like to know why.

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoGuide1);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height){
                    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(WatchVideo.this);;
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: check my answer and try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this It worked for me....

```
  VideoView vv;

        vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        vv.setVideoPath(filename);
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.start();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way

```
MediaController controller;
Videoview videoview;

videoview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
controller = new MediaController(this);

videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoview.setMediaController(controller);
controller.setMediaPlayer(videoview);


videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               int duration = videoview.getDuration();
               videoview.requestFocus();
               videoview.start();
               controller.show();

               Log.d("Video view is prepared","------>");

           }
       });
```